# Insert new XML data into specific locations of an XML

Tags: php, arrays, xml, insert

I need help inserting new XML data into an existing XML structure

So if I had this structure for example:

```
<subject subject="0">
   <datasetOne data="unique1">
      <testData>fdfhgj</testData>
   </datasetOne>
</subject>
<subject subject="2">
   <datasetOne data="unique2"></datasetOne>
   <datasetTwo data="unique3"></datasetTwo>
</subject>
```

How can I insert:

```
<testData>Need to add this</testData>
```

inside dataSetTwo "unique3" for subject 2 so that the xml output would be

```
<subject subject="0">
   <datasetOne data="unique2">
      <testData>fdfhgj</testData>
   </datasetOne>
</subject>
<subject subject="2">
   <datasetOne data="unique2"></datasetOne>
   <datasetTwo data="unique3">
      <testData>Need to add this</testData>
   </datasetTwo>
</subject>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try something like:

```
$data = '
    <doc>
        <subject subject="0">
           <datasetOne data="unique1">
              <testData>fdfhgj</testData>
           </datasetOne>
        </subject>
        <subject subject="2">
           <datasetOne data="unique2"></datasetOne>
           <datasetTwo data="unique3"></datasetTwo>
        </subject>
    </doc>
';

$doc = new DOMDocument();
$doc->loadXML($data);
$xpath = new DOMXpath($doc);
$destination = $xpath->query('//datasetTwo[@data="unique3"]');
$template = $doc->createDocumentFragment();
$template->appendXML('<testData>Need to add this</testData>');
$destination[0]->appendChild($template);
echo $doc->saveXml();
```

Output is your expected output.